# How to get the list from a string in Groovy?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have string `listString = "test1 test-2 [test-3, test-4]"`

Is there a way to get the list from the string

I tried to fetch the list using the below code, but it only returns the last value from the string `test-4]` , which is incorrect

```
toutput = listString.substring(listString.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1)
```

Expected output `[test-3, test-4]`

Once I get the expected output, I want loop through the output list to get the values from the list

Sample code:

```
for (o in toutput){
  println(o) // test-3 and test-4
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you need to pull a string surrounded by `[]` from a string how would looking for the last space help? Why not capture the contents of the `[]` instead then split on `,`?

Comment: This is what I have tried. Was just looking for some suggestion online. And yes I will try to get the contents from [].

Comment: But not sure why the down vote on the question

Comment: Couldn't say, but if I were to guess it's because you're not even trying to get the string past the first `[`. It's pretty obvious that finding the string past the first space wouldn't work at all.

Comment: @Dev, your string does not represent any standard structured format. why not to use the json format for your string?  if you still need to extract something between `[]` - you can use regex like this: `listString.replaceAll(/[^\[]*\[([^\]]+).*/,'$1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the expected answer:

```
def listString = "test1 test-2 [test-3, test-4] test5 [test6, test7]"

def lastItem = (listString.split( '([ ](?=\\[))|(\\][ ])')).last()

assert lastItem == '[test6, test7]'
```